# Migration from ga to gtag.js scripts

Tags: google-analytics, migration, gtag.js, analytics.js

Couldn't find direct migration tutorial or clear description on https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference.
Have limitation to analitic portal access and can't properly to test it.

Need to change next ga scripts under my SPA app to gtag.

```
1. ga('set', 'page', url)
2. ga('send', 'pageview')
3. ga('send', 'event', 'button-interest-request', 'submit-request')
```

I didn't find how should works set on gtag.

I supposed should be something like next strings for strings 1 and 2

```
gtag('event', 'page_view', { page_location: url })
```

And next for string 3

```
gtag('event', 'button-interest-request', {
  'value': 'submit-request'
});
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define at least `event category` and `event action` in `gtag` with this syntax:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

In your situation, like this:

```
gtag('event', 'submit-request', {
  'event_category': 'button-interest-request'
});
```